# how to store and keep skeleton data in kinect (access,read write,threads...)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, concurrency, kinect

I have a question and I am sure somebody has faced this before. I will appreciate your suggestions.

I am working with kinect's skeleton data (joint position information). kinect gives us information of 20 joints in each frame but I need to keep variable number of frames in memory (let's say 2000 frame) and then manipulate it, read and write on it, apply different algorithms on it.

what is the best method in your idea to keep these frames information (consider simultaneous read/write, threads ..). what I found so far is Concurrency class and I want to add each frame into a concurrent vector or queue like:

```
Concurrency::concurrent_vector<NUI_SKELETON_DATA> skeletonFrameQueue;

skeletonFrameQueue.push_back(frameData);
```

that is what I came up with but sometime I have runtime errors and program crashes and it is about heap.

what do you think and what do you suggest about storing these data? is concurrent vectors ok? does they secure with threads? or what is other options ?

thanks in advance for your suggestions.